# Real time clock on an Apple Watch Complication?

Tags: ios, watchkit, clockkit

I am trying to make a complication that works like `Apple's` world clock complication. It would show a time in `HH:mm`, update in sync with the main clock and move backward and forward in time with time travel. It seems like the only text provider that can update like that is `CLKRelativeDateTextProvider`, but that is designed to show the difference between two `NSDates` and while it's fine for timers I can't figure out how to make it display a time of day. `CLKTimeTextProvider` is good for formatting times, but doesn't update with time travel (unless i make new templates for every minute).

Anyone know how `Apple` does it? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use CLKRelativeDateTextProvider to show the difference between the current date and a date in the past? If so, try setting the date to count from to midnight of the current date (0 hour, 0 min, 0 sec). It should count up and be in sync with the apple watch clock.